# Errors when i run my eclipse project

Tags: android

i am trying to make simple database app in eclipse. But when i run with emulator, it give me force close. I have try from this site.

```
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: please add stacktraces

Comment: please try this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: what stacktraces is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete old project from emulator before installing new version.
Actually you can update code in onUpgrade.

Comment: @RahmatAryanto delete from device - go to app manager - find project - delete. eclipse -find dir in package - delete, or find this dir in file system and delete